# Altitudinal gradient in air density at poles

Tags: wind, pressure, air-currents

In the descriptions of polar cells, it is usually described as cold and dense air sinks at poles. But I don't understand why air at high altitude is denser than low altitude at poles.

The polar cells are described as thermally direct cells, directly influenced by the low temperature of surface. I don’t understand how the low surface temperature at poles is related to the (relatively) high density of air at high altitude.

Wikipedia ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_circulation)) says that the air transported from lower latitude (at high altitude) is considerably denser than the underlying air at poles, but I feel it is not explaining anything. In particular, I don't know how it is thermally direct.